# Externalize Config File Java Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I have a  legacy Spring project which has multiple configuration files located in class path.

With the pre-suggested command for compiling and packaging this project I use the following command:

```
mvn package appassembler:assemble -P dev
```

and it make jar file as well as a script for running the project ,and every thing working fine.

But, the challenging  is this approach put all artifacts including config files into the jar file and in deployment, I should  unpackaging the jar file, changing configurations and repackage it again.(e.g. changing ports, IPs and some credentials ,...)

I want to know, is there any way telling appassembler to put config files outside the jar or any other way  to solve the problem with the minor code change ?

Although, it is possible using  -Dspring.config.location but, every time  I compile the project I have to change the script which is created by the appassembler.

Comment: Why using appassembler? Appassembler is not responsible to put something outside you have to configure it that way...

Comment: exactly; I tested some ways mention in the following answer but no expected result is taken. @khmarbaise

Answer (score 1):

[Spring Properties File Outside jar](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-properties-file-outside-jar)

> `spring.config.import=file:./additional.properties,optional:file:/Users/home/config/jdbc.properties`

[Externalized Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.9.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)